# Laravel blade inserting unwanted ternary statements

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a function call in a blade template that expects a string as the first parameter. For some reason, somewhere, Laravel is parsing the string and adding in a ternary because there is a '?' symbol quickly followed by the word 'or'.

Here's an example:

```
{{ $eloquentObject->function('Lorem? ipsum or dolor') }}
```

When blade parses the string it replaces that with this:

```
<?php echo isset($creation->editableHTML('Lorem? ipsum) ? $creation->editableHTML('Lorem? ipsum : dolor '); ?>
```

Someone please tell me how to prevent this nonsense.

Comment: A blind guess but try to escape the question mark char.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the `?` but the `or` that trigger the replacement of your function. It is not really a bug, more an incompatibility : the blade statements are parsed before the PHP ones, and a `{{ STRING or STRING }}` statement is considered a ternary by Blade.

The simplest way would be to either :

- Put your text into a variable in the controller and use the variable in the view
- Use a classic PHP tag to display your value